# Create a first-time logon script for new users

Tags: scripting, windows-10

I am creating generalized images of a Windows 10 machine for my company and some of the software we use requires setting up for each user account. I have a script (.cmd) that can do all of the setup automatically. Is there a way to make the script run each time a new user logs on, but only the first time they log on?

Every guide I have found explains how to assign a script to a user, but I want to have the script automatically assigned and run the first time a new user logs in, without having to go back and assign the script to their account.

The company uses Active Directory to manage user accounts, so options that use AD are perfectly valid.

**EDIT 1:**
I found a guide for doing this in windows 7:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/886089-mdt-log-on-script-for-each-new-user-run-once
However, I cannot find the `locscripts` file or some equivalent on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to trigger a first-run script via the [RunOnce](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/325347/how-to-run-a-logon-script-one-time-when-a-new-user-logs-on-in-windows) registry key. The linked article describes mounting the default user registry hive and adding the RunOnce entry, so that any new profiles created in the future which are based on a copy of this registry will have this setting.